# Iterate to fill nulls pandas

Tags: pandas, loops, null, iteration

I have a table where I would like to fill some null values being the rule a condition between columns. A piece of the table looks like this:

| Master | ID_A | Col_A | Col_B | Col_C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| X | 1 | a | NaN | NaN |
| X | 2 | g | f | o |
| X | 3 | t | s | o |
| Y | 4 | a | d | c |
| Y | 5 | e | r | Nan |

My though was:

- In each row, look for null values.
- When I find a null, look for another row that has the same Master and fill the Null with the ID_A of that row

  - In this case Col_B will be 2 and Col_C will be 3 (first row)
  - And Col_C in the fifth row will be 4

How can I do this? I still find it hard to construct loops but I would like to learn more! Thanks

Comment: Why is it 2 then 3 for the first row? Do you need to iterate through `ID_A`? What if a specific row has more `nan`s than `ID_A`? Restart from 2?

Answer (score 0):

This is harder to do than I thought! Here is a brute force way to do it:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'Master': ['X','X','X','Y','Y'],
               'ID_A': range(1,6),
               'Col_A': ['a','g','t','a','e'],
               'Col_B': [np.nan,'f','s','d','r'],
               'Col_C': [np.nan,'o','o','c',np.nan]})

master_vals = df['Master'].unique()

for val in master_vals:
  df_master = df[df['Master'] == val]
  for row in df_master.index:
    counter = 0
    for col in ['Col_A','Col_B','Col_C']:
      if pd.isnull(df_master.loc[row,col]):
        full_df = df_master.dropna()
        index = full_df.index
        df.loc[row,col] = full_df.loc[index[0]+counter,'ID_A']
        counter += 1
```

For each one of our Master values `[X,Y]`, we select just those rows from the dataframe into `df_master`. Then iterate through the rows and columns we care about from `df_master`, looking for NaNs. If we find one, then we search through `full_df` (the portion of `df_master` that does not contain any NaNs), and select and appropriate value using the counter to help indexing. This leaves us with:

```
df
    Master  ID_A    Col_A   Col_B   Col_C
0   X       1       a       2       3
1   X       2       g       f       o
2   X       3       t       s       o
3   Y       4   a   d   c
4   Y       5   e   r   4
```

This approach may be very slow if your data set is large and may also produce unexpected behaviour unless your data is structured exactly like the example given. Possibly this whole task could be better done using `groupby` and `stack`, but I could not get them to work.